# List items with taxes informations with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables structure and trying to make a report from these:

___BillableDatas

```
|--------|------------|----------|----------|----------|--------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_Date   | BIL_Type | BIL_Item | BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|----------|--------------|
|      1 | 2018-03-01 |    Night |        0 |      105 |            1 |
|      2 | 2018-03-02 |    Night |        0 |      105 |            1 |
|      3 | 2018-03-01 |     Item |       30 |       15 |            2 |
|      4 | 2018-03-01 |     Item |       31 |       21 |            1 |
|      5 | 2018-03-02 |     Item |       30 |       15 |            2 |
|      6 | 2018-03-02 |     Item |       31 |       21 |            1 |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|----------|--------------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 |        Tax 1 |      5.000 |
|      9 |        Tax 2 |      5.000 |
|     10 |        Tax 3 |     19.975 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

*STX_Amount is a percentage.*

___ApplicableTaxesInventory

```
|-----------|-----------|
| ATX_INVId | ATX_STXId |
|-----------|-----------|
|        30 |         9 |
|        30 |        10 |
|        31 |         9 |
|-----------|-----------|
```

- ATX_INVId is the item ID link with ___Inventory.
- ATX_STXId is the tax ID link with ___SalesTaxes.

___Inventory

```
|--------|-----------|----------|
| INV_Id | INV_Name  | INV_Rate |
|--------|-----------|----------|
|     30 | Breakfast |    15.00 |
|     31 |   Paid-TV |    21.00 |
|     32 |      Wine |    19.00 |
|--------|-----------|----------|
```

---

I need to list item like this:

```
|--------|------------|----------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_Date   | BIL_Type | INV_Name | BIL_RateId | BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | ApplicableTaxesRate | ApplicableTaxesName |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|      1 | 2018-03-01 |    Night |     NULL |          0 |   105.00 |            1 |  5.000,19.975,5.000 |   Tax 1,Tax 3,Tax 2 |
|      2 | 2018-03-02 |    Night |     NULL |          0 |   105.00 |            1 |  19.975,5.000,5.000 |   Tax 3,Tax 2,Tax 1 |
|      3 | 2018-03-01 |     Item |     NULL |          0 |    15.00 |            3 |        19.975,5.000 |         Tax 3,Tax 2 |
|      4 | 2018-03-01 |     Item |     NULL |          0 |    21.00 |            1 |                   0 |                   0 |
|      5 | 2018-03-02 |     Item |     NULL |          0 |    15.00 |            2 |        5.000,19.975 |         Tax 2,Tax 3 |
|      6 | 2018-03-02 |     Item |     NULL |          0 |    21.00 |            1 |                   0 |                   0 |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

---

Explications on the totals:

- 5.000,5.000,19.975 = tax amounts comma separated for the item
- Tax 1,Tax 2, Tax 3 = tax names comma separated for the item

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT BIL_Id
    , BIL_Date
    , BIL_Type
    , BIL_RateId
    , BIL_Rate
    , BIL_Quantity
    , GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(STX_Amount, "0")) AS ApplicableTaxesRate
    , GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(STX_TaxeName, "0")) AS ApplicableTaxesName
FROM ___BillableDatas
LEFT JOIN ___Inventory
    ON ___BillableDatas.BIL_Item=___Inventory.INV_Id
LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes
    ON FIND_IN_SET(STX_Id, BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
GROUP BY BIL_Id
ORDER BY BIL_Date ASC
```

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebc997

Thanks.

Comment: Update: just remove the `WHERE BIL_BookingId='1'`.

Comment: How are you using columns in your query that don't exist in the tables? `BIL_ApplicableTaxes` and `BIL_Status`?

Comment: @clinomaniac: first, thanks for your help. `BIL_ApplicableTaxes` was my alias to get all the taxes. `BIL_Status` you could remove it as it's not mandatory for the example. The code is now updated.

Comment: How do you determine what taxes are applicable to each bill line?

Comment: @clinomaniac, because on ___BillableDatas, `BIL_Item` is link with `ATX_INVId` in ___ApplicableTaxesInventory. And `ATX_STXId` is linked to `STX_Id` in ___SalesTaxes. Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as answer cause comment would not format.

```
SELECT BIL_Id
    , BIL_Date
    , BIL_Type
    , BIL_RateId
    , BIL_Rate
    , BIL_Quantity
    , GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(STX_Amount, "0")) AS ApplicableTaxesRate
    , GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(STX_TaxeName, "0")) AS ApplicableTaxesName 
FROM ___BillableDatas BD 
LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxesInventory AI
    ON FIND_IN_SET(AI.ATX_INVId, BD.BIL_Item)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ___SalesTaxes ST
    ON AI.ATX_STXId = ST.STX_Id
GROUP BY BIL_Id
ORDER BY BIL_Date ASC
```

This query seems to give results as you would expect but the data is not matching since the sample data doesn't match the question. Let me know if this is not what you expect.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3daaf/2